# Serialized settings in rest api

Tags: options, rest-api, settings-api

I have registered settings and need it to be showed in REST API.

```
$args = [
    'show_in_rest' => true
];
register_setting('default_sidebars', 'default_sidebars', $args);
```

When I save a single value and then request data on endpoint `/wp-json/wp/v2/settings`, everything works perfectly.

But the problem is that I save serialized data like this.

```
a:2:{s:4:"post";s:7:"general";s:4:"blog";s:9:"sidebar_1";}
```

Now I would expect in response something like this:

```
default_sidebars: {
  post: "general",
  blog: "sidebar_1"
}
```

But instead I got `default_sidebars: null`.

What should I do to get my data in REST API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### JSON Schema

It's supported if you explicitly register the **object JSON schema** as:

```
$args = array(
    'show_in_rest' => array(
        'schema' => array(
            'type'       => 'object',
            'properties' => array(
                'post' => array(
                    'type' => 'string',
                ),
                'blog' => array(
                    'type' => 'string',
                ),
            )
        ),
    ),
);

register_setting( 'default_sidebars', 'default_sidebars', $args );
```

Resulting in the following object:

```
default_sidebars: {
  post: "general",
  blog: "sidebar_1"
}
```

in `/wp-json/wp/v2/settings` for the serialized option data:

```
a:2:{s:4:"post";s:7:"general";s:4:"blog";s:9:"sidebar_1";}
```

See similar object schema support for `register_meta()` in 5.3:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/03/wp-5-3-supports-object-and-array-meta-types-in-the-rest-api/

Comment: Great, this works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Silly me, I should've dug deeper on the `type` & `properties` when I actually saw them [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L1244) yesterday! Anyway, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

*Not sure if there's a **better** way when using the default Settings endpoint, but this works for me.*

You can use the [`rest_pre_get_setting` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_pre_get_setting/) to convert the data to a JSON-encoded string:

```php
add_filter( 'rest_pre_get_setting', function ( $value, $name ) {
    if ( 'default_sidebars' === $name ) {
        $value = json_encode( get_option( $name ) );
    }
    return $value;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Then for example in JavaScript, you can parse the value into an object using `JSON.parse()`:

```php
// Note: I intentionally omitted the authentication/nonce part.
fetch( 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/settings' )
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( settings => console.log( JSON.parse( settings.default_sidebars ) ) );
```

Or in PHP (e.g. you make the API request from another site using PHP), you can do:

```php
$settings = json_decode( $data ); // assume data is the REST API response body
$default_sidebars = json_decode( $settings->default_sidebars );
```

### Additional Notes

The `null` value is because `get_option()` unserializes the data to an array and the REST API controller for the Settings endpoint is using [`rest_validate_value_from_schema()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_validate_value_from_schema/) to validate the option value (i.e. after being unserialized), which when it's not of the currently supported types (string, boolean, integer and number) — see [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/), then the function returns an error and the Settings endpoint/controller returns a `null` for that specific option.

### Alternate Solution

You can [create a custom REST API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) and with the following example, you would make request to `/wp-json/myplugin/v1/setting/<option name>` where `<option name>` could be `default_sidebars` in your case:

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/setting/(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)', [
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => function ( $request ) {
            return get_option( $request->get_param( 'name' ) );
        },
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return current_user_can( 'manage_options' ); // you should keep this
        },
    ] );
} );
```

Comment: Ok, maybe this is not the most elegant solution, but do the work. Thanks for help!