# Save default options as an array of options and display in REST API

Tags: rest-api, options

I am trying to save array of options and display them in the rest api.
I know I can store the options one by one with `register_setting`, but I think saving all the options in an array is better than saving each option individually, since it will be just one request instead of four different requests. However, the response I get is `awg_settings: null`

```
$general_options = [
    'is_show_post'     => true,
    'is_show_page'    => true,
    'is_show_cpt'      => '',
    'featured_post_id' => '',
];

// register plugin options
add_option( 'awg_settings', $general_options );

register_setting(
    'awg_option_fields',
    'awg_settings',
    [
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'type'         => 'array',
    ]
);
```

```
    componentDidMount() {
        // fetch all plugin options
        api.loadPromise.then(() => {
            this.settings = new api.models.Settings();
            const { isAPILoaded } = this.state;

            if (!isAPILoaded) {
                this.settings.fetch().then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue thanks to this answer: [Serialized settings in rest api](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/360207/serialized-settings-in-rest-api#answer-360237).

I was able to store all the options as a json object:

```
/**
 * Create plugin options schema as an object and prepare it for the rest api. 
 * WP >=5.3
 */
function my_register_settings() {

    $general_options = [
        'show_in_rest' => [
            'schema' => [
                'type'       => 'object',
                'properties' => [
                    'is_show_post'     => [
                        'type'    => 'string',
                        'default' => 'true',
                    ],
                    'is_show_page'     => [
                        'type'    => 'string',
                        'default' => 'true',
                    ],
                    'is_show_cpt'      => [
                        'type'    => 'string',
                        'default' => '',
                    ],
                    'featured_post_id' => [
                        'type'    => 'string',
                        'default' => '',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    // register plugin options as an object
    register_setting(
        'awg_settings',
        'awg_options',
        $general_options
    );

}

add_action( 'init', 'my_register_settings' );
```